# Application Breaks when adding custom component as import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am having an issue where I have created two components "TaskInputField.js" and "TaskItem.js" and when I import them into the file I want to use them in, the browser window I am viewing the app on turns completely blank (using expo). Can post screenshots of what I mean if needed.

This has never happened to me before where simply importing a file breaks the application.

If I remove the imports from GroceryList.js and remove where I use them in the file, everything else runs just fine. I followed a guide for most of this also so I am unsure what is happening.

Thanks in advance.

For reference:

**TaskInputField.js**

```
 import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { KeyboardAvoidingView, StyleSheet, View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, } from "react-native";
import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons'; 

export default TaskInputField = (props) => {
    const [task, setTask] = useState();

    const handleAddTask = (value) => {
        props.addTask(value);
        setTask(null);
    }

    return (
        <KeyboardAvoidingView 
        behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
        style={styles.container}
      >
        <TextInput style={styles.inputField} value={task} onChangeText={text => setTask(text)} placeholder={'Write a task'} placeholderTextColor={'#fff'}/>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleAddTask(task)}>
                <View style={styles.button}>
                    <MaterialIcons name="keyboard-arrow-up" size={24} color="black" />
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
}
```

**TaskItem.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, } from "react-native";
import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

export default TaskItem = (props) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.indexContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.index}>{props.index}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.taskContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.task}>{props.task}</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.deleteTask()}>
                    <MaterialIcons style={styles.delete} name="delete" size={18} color='#fff' />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
```

}

**I am implementing these here in GroceryList.js**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Keyboard, ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import TaskInputField from '../../components/TaskInputField';
import TaskItem from '../../components/TaskItem';


export default function GroceryList() {

      const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

  const addTask = (task) => {
    if (task == null) return;
    setTasks([...tasks, task]);
    Keyboard.dismiss();
  }

  const deleteTask = (deleteIndex) => {
    setTasks(tasks.filter((value, index) => index != deleteIndex));
  }

    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.heading}>Grocery List</Text>
      <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
        {
        tasks.map((task, index) => {
          return (
            <View key={index} style={styles.taskContainer}>
              <TaskItem index={index + 1} task={task} deleteTask={() => deleteTask(index)}/>
            </View>
          );
        })
      }
      </ScrollView>
      <TaskInputField addTask={addTask}/>
    </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"expo does not load"_?

Comment: I will edit my post. UI and functionality work fine without the imports, but when I add them, the window goes blank, like something broke.

Comment: In that case and assuming by _"window"_ you mean the browser, check the dev-tools _Console_ for errors

Comment: you can try checking the console for any errors. also, while importing in the GroceryList file, is the ../ 2 times a typo? sometimes such folder names can cause trouble

Comment: No unfortunately the pathing is correct, and there are no console errors fml